# Jackson: Generate Jackson classes from XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, jackson

Similar to JAXB generating JAXB classes to a given XSD, does Jackson provide any utility to generate Jackson classes from XSD or JSON.

JAXB class geberator has generated a set of classes for XSD schema defined. For example, for polymorphic types JAXB has the following annotation to identify the name based on XML Element name.

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "Dog", type = Dog.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "Cat", type = Cat.class)
})
protected List<Animal> animal;
```

Is it possible to create similar classes in Jackson. ie., to identify the type based in XML element name.

Comment: For the googlers: Although Jackson can handle JAXB annotations, @XmlElements is not well-supported. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/issues/127 for details.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson can add such information automatically (see [@JsonTypeInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html)). For example:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
protected List<Animal> animal;
```

Or use that annotation with [@JsonSubTypes](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSubTypes.html):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
      include = As.PROPERTY, 
      property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "Dog"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat")
    })
protected List<Animal> animal;
```

This [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) is useful.